# How to bind a simple .net property to a label and have it auto update

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, properties

I'm kinda new to data binding and obviously don't really understand it.  I'm trying to bind a simple .net property to a label, and have that label updated whenever the property is changed.  It's not working and i'm not sure where the problem lies.

Here is my XAML

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>

 <Button Name="bChangeProperty" Click="bChangeProperty_Click">Change Property</Button>
```

Here is my UserControl cs file

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   private MyObjectClass _myObject;
   public MyObjectClass MyProperty
   {
       get { return _myObject;}
       set
       {
          if (_myObject != value)
          {
              _myObject = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty"); 
          }
        }
   }


   public MyUserControl(MyObjectClass obj)
   {
      if (obj == null)
      {
          obj = new MyObjectClass();
          obj.Name = "Frank";
      }
      MyProperty= obj;
      base.DataContext = MyProperty;
   }

   //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
      //PropertyChanged is always null, don't really understand this part
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }


   private void bChangeProperty_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       //Create a new object, and set it to the MyProperty Property - which I thought
       //would update the label, but it doesn't
       MyObjectClass newObject = new MyObjectClass();
       newObject.Name = "Bob";

       MyProperty= newObject;
   }
```

Here is the MyObjectClass

```
public class MyObjectClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The inital bind works, it will set the Label to "Frank", but when I click the button and the object is changed, the label won't update.  This is just an example of something "like" what i'm trying to do.

Do I have to set PropertyChanged to something somewhere?  I kinda thought thats what the XAML was suppose to do, but seeing how it is always null, apparently it's not.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");` ihh the property name in a string. Smelly. I recommend the the lamda expression trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MyObjectClass` and fire `PropertyChanged` after `MyObjectClass.Name` was changed.

```
public class MyObjectClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name"); 
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {      
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the `DataContext` in your constructor to point to the initial "Frank" object, but when you change the instance that `MyProperty` points to you do not update the `DataContext` accordingly.

Therefore, the direct solution is to add this:

```
private void bChangeProperty_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //Create a new object, and set it to the MyProperty Property - which I thought
   //would update the label, but it doesn't
   MyObjectClass newObject = new MyObjectClass();
   newObject.Name = "Bob";

   MyProperty= newObject;
   this.DataContext = MyProperty; // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

However, the *correct* solution is to not set the `DataContext` at all and simply change the `Binding`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=MyProperty.Name} ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, updating the DataContext whenever the object is changed worked for me.  Changing the Label binding to the 'MyProperty.Name' leaves it blank all the time.  The MyObjectClass is from a Class Library that i'm not really allowed to change so for now the rather 'incorrect' updating the DataContext will have to do for me.